# Extension method not found?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

So after some looking around and attempting to correct this issue myself, I'm stuck. I looked at the following posts and ensured that I've included all assemblies as they stated (which I had done prior to coming here, but double checked to make sure):

- [Extension methods not showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992135/extension-methods-not-showing)

  - This one tells me to ensure the namespace containing the extension is included.
- [Extension methods not recognized.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594280/extension-methods-not-recognized)

  - This one tells me that all relevant assemblies should also be included.

After double checking my file that has the extension, and the file attempting to use the extension; are there any other possible reasons why an extension method wouldn't be found?

```
// Extension Class.
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct2D1;
namespace MyNamespace.Engine {
    public static class Utilities {
        public static Vector3 PointToNDC(this SpriteBatch sb, Size2 screenSize, Point p) {
            float x = 2.0f * p.X / screenSize.Width - 1.0f;
            float y = 1.0f - 2.0f * p.Y / screenSize.Height;
            return new Vector3(x, y, 0);
        }
    }
}

// Usage Class.
using MyNamespace.Engine;
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct2D1;
namespace MyNamespace.Prefabs {
    public class Sprite {
        public void Draw() {
            SpriteBatch.PointToNDC(new Size2(50, 50), new Point(0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Note

Any typos in the code are actual typos here not in the code itself.

---

### Update

As [@Brian Rasmussen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38206/brian-rasmussen) pointed out in the comments, I didn't call the method from an instance of the object being extended. I haven't had my coffee yet, so my apologies, at least this was a simple fix!

```
SpriteBatch sb = new SpriteBatch(...);
sb.PointToNDC(...); // <- Works.
```

Comment: Is the extension in other dll?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but you're not calling `PointToNDC` as an extension method. To do that, you need an instance of `SpriteBatch`.

Comment: Are you trying to call the extension on a static class? Does not look like you are trying to call it on an instance of `SpriteBatch`

Comment: Are you expecting ` SpriteBatch.PointToNDC(new Size2(50, 50), new Point(0, 0));` to call `public static Vector3 PointToNDC(this SpriteBatch sb, Size2 screenSize, Point p) { /*code*/}`?  It won't.  You need to call it on an instance of a SpriteBatch: `var sb = new SpriteBatch(); var v3 = sb.PointToNDC(/*params*/);`

Comment: @BrianRasmussen AHHHHHHHHHHHH How did I not see that.... If you write up a brief answer I'll mark it as accepted. I knew it was something simple that I was overlooking.

Comment: Since your `PointToNDC` doesn't even do anything with the `sb` parameter, there's probably no point in having it be an extension method at all versus just being a regular static method on a static class.

Comment: @MattBurland I'm following Frank Luna's DirectX11 book [see this sample](http://www.d3dcoder.net/Data/Resources/SpritesAndText.pdf) and it's all written in C++; the C# library SharpDX doesn't contain a definition for this method though apparently in C++ it has a definition but no implementation. So Frank implements the method; now I could just create a static method but I would like future developers that take this project over to be able to follow the same book if needed.

Comment: @PerpetualJ: There's still no sense making it an extension method. You are now in your update creating a throw away `SpriteBatch` just so you can call an extension method which does nothing to the instance of `SpriteBatch` at all. Make the signature of the method `public static Vector3 PointToNDC(Size2 screenSize, Point p)` and call it as `Utilities.PointToNDC(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call `PointToNDC` as an extension method you need an instance of `SpriteBatch`.